# Different use (not the most common one) of else clause in python

Tags: python, generator, if-statement

There is an exercise in 6.00x edX whose answer's suggestion provided by them is as follows:

```
def genPrimes():
    primes = []   # primes generated so far
    last = 1      # last number tried
    while True:
        last += 1
        for p in primes:
            if last % p == 0:
                break
        else:
            primes.append(last)
            yield last
```

Looking to the identation I can clearly see that this ELSE is not related to the IF. I thought it was a bug but when I executed, the code was fine and I can't understand what is happening, what does that ELSE does?

Comment: I would guess the `else` clause executes if the for loop doesn't run once, e.g. if `primes==[]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`else` part of your `for loop` executes, when your `for loop` runs successfully without `breaking` in the middle of the `iteration`.

So, in your example, : -

```
if last % p == 0:
      break
```

if your above `if condition` in for loop becomes true in some iteration, it will break out of your for loop, and in that case your else will not execute.

Answer (score 4):

It is executed when the `for` loop is done going through the list. But, in the case of the example you have. If the `break` is called the `else` will not be executed.